# Settings schema 'org.gnome.mutter.x11' is not installed

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

so I tried to install gnome 40 today. Once it was done, I rebooted my pc, but was stuck on a "Something went wrong" screen, so I checked journalctl, which says "Settings schema 'org.gnome.mutter.x11' is not installed". Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Edit: I already have both mutter and mutter-common installed.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? 
To get Gnome 40 on Ubuntu, you need to add a third-party PPA (AKA a personal package archive) to your system. To do it, use the apt-add-repository command down below. After adding in the new Gnome 40 PPA, you'll need to run the update command on your Ubuntu PC. This command will finish configuring the Gnome 40 PPA.

Answer (score 1):

See the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1875243).

> Once I install the package `mutter-common`, the crash does not occur and I am able to use gnome-control-center.

Comment: Hi, I already have that installed, and it still doesn't work.